# Should rep from other (non-trilogy) SE 1.0 sites count for commitment phase?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51, commitment-phase

Given that there are several other fairly-active SE-based sites, with high-rep users, would it be reasonable to count that rep in the commitment phase? I presume it's *technically* possible, given that all of the sites are owned by SO (but could be wrong).

For instance, I don't have a lot of rep on SO, but have a fair amount on [UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/) (as do a lot of other people). So we should have a good understanding of the site mechanics, which seems to be what you're looking for when people commit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**None** of those sites are owned by Stack Overflow. They are privately owned so we don't even have the *right* to access their database on that basis.

But even if we received *special permission* from the site owners, the code bases are different and the databases are different between Stack Exchange and the legacy sites. While it's not technically *impossible* to link the two, it would be terribly impractical.

Comment: I understand the desire to do everything automatically, but could exceptions be made on a case by case examination? SharePointOveflow.com is publicly accessible and it is easy to see that there is enough interest in it to move to a beta in the Area51 process.

Answer (score 9):

I hereby grant permission to access the MathOverflow database for this purpose, and furthermore offer to prepare a list of users and reputations in any format desired. :-)

Comment: Have you had any response from the SO people?

Comment: No. I'm not too surprised, it's mostly unnecessary work for them, to be fair.

Comment: In case it makes a difference (I suspect it doesn't), I hereby extend the same offer.