# Please include Math Overflow reputation in the Area 51 commit count

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, commitment-phase, mathoverflow

I am aware of the reasoning behind the [commit percentage calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) on Area 51:

> [we require] lots of users with high rep, because we know that those users contribute a lot and know how the system works

Why should that exclude the high-rep users from active SE 1.0 sites such as MO? This would broaden the core seed group from ["programmer and foo"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/how-should-critical-mass-be-calculated/53696#53696) to "mathematician and foo," &c.

- If it is a technical problem, can you please try to address it?
- if it is a matter of principle, can you please explain?

Comment: related: [Linking in MathOverflow account with the others?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54320/linking-in-mathoverflow-account-with-the-others)

Comment: I think the trouble was that MO is a SE-1.0 site not owned by the SE team and it is therefore considered illegal to access their data. However I assume if the MO team would agree (e.g. upon request on http://meta.mathoverflow.net) this might be arrangeable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, found it: Robert's answer on [Should rep from other (non-trilogy) SE 1.0 sites count for commitment phase?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/should-rep-from-other-non-trilogy-se-1-0-sites-count-for-commitment-phase/53799#53799). The problem seems to be technical

**Edit** Also note [Scott Morrison's reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/should-rep-from-other-non-trilogy-se-1-0-sites-count-for-commitment-phase/54001#54001) on the same question. Unfortunately this didn't help.

Comment: it's a little unfortunate. I'm involved with mathoverflow, and also in  area51 with a related proposal that draws heavily from the MO crowd (it's on Theoretical Computer Science). So my hard earned rep on MO counts for nothing in our recently entered commit phase.

Comment: @Suresh MO should definitely be allowed to upgrade to SE-2.0 and then it would join the accumulated rep network. However, this will probably still take quite a while to happen

Comment: I understand. Is there any way to adjust commit calculations for sites populated by pre-SE-2.0 members (i.e not using the reputation counts, since that's hard, but maybe relaxing the calculations a bit?)

Comment: @Suresh I'm afraid not many will read this question here, especially not someone who actually knows the answer :-/ maybe you should "ask" another feature-request for this and then post a link here

Comment: ok I just did it. the link is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55386/adjusting-commit-calculations-for-pre-se-2-0-groups